# Checking arrays in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm collecting rows of answers from a database which are made in to arrays. Something like:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < event.result.length; i++) {     
    var data = event.result[i]; 
    var answer:Array = new Array(data["question_id"], data["focus_id"], data["attempts"], data["category"], data["answer"], data["correct"], data["score"]);

    trace("answer: " + answer);
    restoreAnswer(answer, i);

}
```

Now, if I `trace answer`, I typically get something like:
answer: 5,0,2,IK,1.a,3.1,0
answer: 5,0,1,IK,2.a,3.1,0
answer: 4,1,1,AK,3,3,2

From this we see that focus_id 0 (second array item) in question_id 5 (first array item) has been attempted twice (third array item), and I only want to use the last attempt in my `restoreAnswer` function.

My problem is that first attempt answers override the second attempts since the first are parsed last it seems. How do I go about only calling my `restoreAnswer` only when appropriate?

The options are:
1 attempts, correct score (2 points)
2 attempts, correct score (1 points)
1 attempt, wrong score (0 points)
2 attemps, wrong score (0 points)

There can be multiple focus_id in each question_id.

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider having the DB query return only the most recent attempt, or if that doesn't work efficiently, return the data in attempt order.  You may score question 5 twice, but at least it'll score correctly on the last pass.

You can also filter or sort the data you get back from the server.

Comment: Thanks!
I'd like to re-write as little as possible, and the restoreAnswer function works well. I just need some logic as when to call it. 

It would have to check if a focus_id appears twice in a question_id, and then fire the restoreAnswer function. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it within the loop (and not very strong array skills!).

Answer (score 0):

Michael Brewer-Davis suggested using the database query to resolve this; normally speaking, this would be the right solution.

If you wait until you get it back from the web method call or whatever in AS3, then consider creating an additional Vector variable:

```
var vAttempts:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>(this.m_iNumQuestions);
```

You mentioned that *it seems* that everything is sorted so that earlier attempts come last.  First you want to make sure that's true.  If so, then before you do any call to `restoreAnswer()`, you'll want to check `vAttempts` to make sure that you have not already called `restoreAnswer()` for that `question_id` and `focus_id`:

```
if (!vAttempts[data["question_id"]])
{
    vAttempts[data["question_id"]] = new Vector.<int>(); // ensuring a second dimension
}

if (vAttempts[data["question_id"]].indexOf(data["focus_id"]) == -1)
{
    restoreAnswer(answer, i);
    vAttempts[data["question_id"]].push(data["focus_id"]);
}
```

So optimizing this just a little bit, what you'll have is as follows:

```
private final function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
    var vAttempts:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>(this.m_iNumQuestions);
    var result:Object = event.result;
    var iLength:int = result.length;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < iLength; i++) {     
        var data = result[i];
        var iQuestionID:int = data["question_id"];
        var iFocusID:int = data["focus_id"];

        var answer:Array = [iQuestionID, iFocusID, data["attempts"],
                data["category"], data["answer"], data["correct"], data["score"]];
        trace("answer: " + answer);

        var vFocusIDs:Vector.<int> = vAttempts[iQuestionID];
        if (!vFocusIDs) {
            vAttempts[iQuestionID] = new <int>[iFocusID];
            restoreAnswer(answer, i);
        } else if (vFocusIDs.indexOf(iFocusID) == -1) {
            restoreAnswer(answer, i);
            vFocusIDs.push(iFocusID);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** In AS3, Arrays can skip over certain indexes, but Vectors can't.  So if your program doesn't already have some sort of foreknowledge as to the number of questions, you'll need to change `vAttempts` from a Vector to an Array.  Also account for whether question IDs are 0-indexed (as this question assumes) or 1-indexed.